# Installing compiled program previously installed in other folder

Tags: software-installation, compiling, path, libraries

I compiled `gcc` and dependencies (`gmp`, `mpfr`, `mpc`) in specific folder to get backup of these folders in other not repeat the compile process, and pass to another machines.

**MAKE** Only for update

```
$ tar zxvf make-4.2.1.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/make-4.2.1/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/make
$ sh ./build.sh
$ ./make check
$ sudo ./make install
```

Dependencies for GCC

**GMP**

```
$ tar Jxvf gmp-6.1.2.tar.xz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/gmp-6.1.2/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/gmp --enable-cxx --disable-static
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**MPFR**

```
$ tar -zxvf mpfr-3.1.6.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/mpfr --disable-static --enable-thread-safe --with-gmp=/usr/local/Custom/gmp
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**MPC**

```
$ tar -zxvf mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/mpc-1.0.3/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/mpc --with-gmp=/usr/local/Custom/gmp -with-mpfr=/usr/local/Custom/mpfr
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/gcc.html

**GCC**

```
$ tar zxvf gcc-7.2.0.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/gcc-7.2.0/
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/gcc --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-lenguages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/usr/local/Custom/gmp -with-mpfr=/usr/local/Custom/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/Custom/mpc
$ time make -j $(nproc)
```

The time taken is **more than 8 hours**

```
real    506m8.644s
user    461m46.399s
sys 30m54.429s
$ 

$ time sudo make install
```

The time taken is

```
real    1m52.495s
user    0m35.449s
sys 0m35.820s
$
```

NOW the Hierarchy is:

```
$ tree -d /usr/local/Custom/
/usr/local/Custom/
├── gcc
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   │   └── c++
│   │       └── 7.2.0
│   │           ├── backward
│   │           ├── bits
│   │           ├── debug
│   │           ├── decimal
│   │           ├── experimental
│   │           │   └── bits
│   │           ├── ext
│   │           │   └── pb_ds
│   │           │       └── detail
│   │           │           ├── REMOVED IN ORDER TO MAKE SHORT THIS QUESTION
│   │           ├── parallel
│   │           ├── profile
│   │           │   └── impl
│   │           ├── tr1
│   │           ├── tr2
│   │           └── x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
│   │               ├── bits
│   │               └── ext
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── gcc
│   │       └── x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
│   │           └── 7.2.0
│   │               ├── REMOVED IN ORDER TO MAKE SHORT THIS QUESTION
│   ├── lib64
│   ├── libexec
│   │   └── gcc
│   │       └── x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
│   │           └── 7.2.0
│   │               ├── install-tools
│   │               └── plugin
│   └── share
│       ├── gcc-7.2.0
│       │   └── python
│       │       └── libstdcxx
│       │           └── v6
│       ├── info
│       ├── locale
│       │   ├── REMOVED IN ORDER TO MAKE SHORT THIS QUESTION
│       └── man
│           ├── man1
│           └── man7
├── gmp
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── share
│       └── info
├── make
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   └── share
│       ├── info
│       ├── locale
│       │   ├── REMOVED IN ORDER TO MAKE SHORT THIS QUESTION
│       └── man
│           └── man1
├── mpc
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── share
│       └── info
├── mpfr
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── share
│       ├── doc
│       │   └── mpfr
│       │       └── examples
│       └── info
```

Now, in the destiny machines the `Original locations` are:

```
$ whereis gmp mpfr mpc
gmp: /usr/include/gmp.h
mpfr: /usr/include/mpfr.h
mpc: /usr/include/mpc.h
$ which make gcc
/usr/local/bin/make
/usr/bin/gcc
$
```

The questions

**How can update (`make`, `gmp`, `mpfr`, `mpc` and `gcc`) the another machines with these folders?**

- Replacing the old commands (in its `Original locations`)?
- Preserving the old commands (in another folder like: `/my/Folder/Commands`)?

Comment: You should copy your `/usr/local/Custom` directory as is (even if poorly named) and adapt your `$PATH` so that you use things preferentially there.

Answer (score 0):

**Doesn't work for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`**

```
$ more /etc/environment 
PATH=/usr/local/Custom/make/bin:/usr/local/Custom/gcc/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
CPATH=/usr/local/Custom/make/include:/usr/local/Custom/gmp/include:/usr/local/Custom/mpfr/include:/usr/local/Custom/mpc/include
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Custom/gmp/lib:/usr/local/Custom/mpfr/lib:/usr/local/Custom/mpc/lib
$
```

**Trying with `root` user**

```
$ more /root/.bash_profile 
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Custom/gmp/lib:/usr/local/Custom/mpfr/lib:/usr/local/Custom/mpc/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$
```

In both cases I get:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$
```

**HERE My Solution for `lib`!**

```
$ more /etc/ld.so.conf.d/custom.conf
/usr/local/Custom/gmp/lib
/usr/local/Custom/mpfr/lib
/usr/local/Custom/mpc/lib
```

**HERE My Solution for `include` and `bin` !**

```
$ more /etc/environment 
PATH=/usr/local/Custom/make/bin:/usr/local/Custom/gcc/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/
sbin:/bin:/sbin
CPATH=/usr/local/Custom/make/include:/usr/local/Custom/gmp/include:/usr/local/Custom/mpfr/include:/usr/local/Custom/mpc/include
$
```

Now I check:

```
$ which make gcc
/usr/local/Custom/make/bin/make
/usr/local/Custom/gcc/bin/gcc
$

$  cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/gcc --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-lenguages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/usr/local/Custom/gmp -with-mpfr=/usr/local/Custom/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/Custom/mpc
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/local/Custom/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/Custom/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Custom/make/include
 /usr/local/Custom/gmp/include
 /usr/local/Custom/mpfr/include
 /usr/local/Custom/mpc/include
 /usr/local/Custom/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Custom/gcc/include
 /usr/local/Custom/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

**Unfortunately I get:**

```
$ whereis gmp mpfr mpc
gmp:mpfr:mpc:[ ~]$
```